# Error on convert pdf to png using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

Give error while convert pdf to png by using below command :
convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 85 655382767_1460008284.pdf[0-9] 655382767_1460008284.png

OS : Redhat 64 bit 6.7
ImageMagick : version 6.7.2-7 2015-02-27 Q16
Ghostscript : GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)

Its give below error :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
Operand stack:
1 true
Execution stack:
%interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 4 1 8 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 1745 0 9 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:1157/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:27/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 28
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: Postscript delegate failed 655382767_1460008284.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/664. convert: missing an image filename655382767_1460008284.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

[image]

Please help me to fix it.
Also some other pdf files are converted perfactly to png.

Please find attachment of pdf file which are making issue on converting to png using Imagemagick convert command.

[enter link description here](http://162.209.121.83/media/designtool/UploadedImages/9391f364a26cc3b6095ae3f78e86458e/775167223_1461737009.pdf)

Comment: Works fine with ImageMagick 6.9+. Try updating your ImageMagick.

Comment: Looks like an index error. You can only extract existing pages 0-7, not 8 or 9. Also, you should really upgrade to ImageMagick 6.9+

Comment: How we can know number of pages in pdf file ? Also I had tried some other pdf files which has 2 to 6 pages and passes [0-9] on conversion. But it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

ioerror means there was an I/O error, which may mean that the disk is full, or there was some other problem. Try using a lower resolution ('density' in IM terms I think). Given that you have 8 pages, each page is 32x76 inches and you have a resolution of 300 dpi you are looking at producing a lot of data, about 1.8Gb if depth=8 means greyscale.

There could be any number of other reasons why there was an ioerror, the next thing to do is to try a more recent version of Ghostscript 8.70 is now 6 years old..... As Mark Setchell suggests you could also try using a more recent version of ImageMagick, though I doubt that will help, since its clearly an error being returned from Ghostscript.